# Ошибка в запросе (одинаковые видимые имена)

Tags: sql-server

Пытаюсь реализовать запрос: Определить преподавателя, который в сессию принимает экзамены у наибольшего числа студентов. Но к сожалению все безуспешно, выдает ошибку `Объекты "Дисциплины" и "Дисциплины" в предложении FROM имеют одинаковые видимые имена. Используйте корреляционные имена, чтобы различать их`. Как это можно исправить?[image: Схема БД]

```
SELECT Преподаватели.ФИО, SUM(Группы.КоличествоСтудентов) AS количество
FROM Преподаватели,Группы,Контроль,Дисциплины
INNER JOIN Дисциплины ON Преподаватели.Дисциплины=Дисциплины.Название,
Дисциплина INNER JOIN Контроль ON Контроль.Дисциплина=Дисциплина.Название, 
Группы INNER JOIN Контроль ON Группы.КодГруппы=Контроль.Группа
WHERE Преподаватели.Контроль="экзамен"
GROUP BY Преподаватели.ФИО
ORDER BY SUM(Группы.КоличествоСтудентов) DESC
```

Comment: FROM Преподаватели,Группы,Контроль,Дисциплины  - избавьтесь от такого соединения, сделайте через правильный JOIN

Comment: SELECT Преподаватели.ФИО, SUM(КоличествоСтудентов) AS [Количество студентв], MAX(Контроль.ВидКонтроля) AS [Вид контроля]
FROM Группы INNER JOIN
Контроль ON КодГруппы = Контроль.Группа INNER JOIN
Преподаватели ON Контроль.Преподаватель = Преподаватели.КодПреподавателя
WHERE Контроль.ВидКонтроля='экзамен'
GROUP BY Преподаватели.ФИО
ORDER BY SUM(Группы.КоличествоСтудентов) DESC Так что ли?

Comment: вам виднее, поле Группа - это КодГруппы, тогда похоже

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного доработал ответ @user393275 , т.к. не совсем понял для чего там был использован `MAX(Контроль.ВидКонтроля)`

У меня получилось что-то вот в таком роде:

```
SELECT преподаватели.ФИО, SUM(КоличествоСтудентов) AS [Количество студентов]
FROM [Преподаватели] преподаватели
    INNER JOIN [Контроль] контроль ON преподаватели.КодПреподавателя = контроль.Преподаватель
    INNER JOIN [Группы] группы ON контроль.Группа = группы.КодГруппы
WHERE контроль.ВидКонтроля = N'экзамен'
GROUP BY преподаватели.ФИО
ORDER BY SUM(КоличествоСтудентов) DESC
```

Comment: условия фильтрация присоединяемой таблицу убирайте в джойн, какой они в основном where нужны?

Comment: @taran , не совсем понимаю для чего убирать фильтрацию в join. В join я определяю присоединяемые таблицы и условия соединения, а потом уже фильтрую записи для того, чтобы не загружать информацией join.
Почему вы считаете, что условия фильтрации должны располагаться в join?

Comment: потому что это фильтрация присоединяемой таблицы, и на выходе джонйна вы получите меньший по выборке результат, что при следующих джойнах приведет к меньшему числу строк в результате запроса, который уже потом будет фильтроваться. Если что-то можно отфильтровать сразу - делайте сразу. 
Тут иногда попадаются вопросы а-ля "мой запрос рабоатет 5 минут", как ускорить. Напишут джойнов получив 500млн строк результата а потом фильтруют, а перенос условий сразу в джойн снизит это до 15 секунд.

Comment: @taran, спасибо, интересно. Я как-то закостенело воспринимал, что в JOIN условия соединений и даже не задумывался, что можно сразу отфильтровать большое количество строк таким образом. Попробую воспроизвести на больших таблицах